# WebkitSpeechRecognition Architecture

Tags: webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

I know WebkitSpeechRecognition is only available on the chromium browser. However I am wondering how it converts the voice into text?

I tried to monitor the network log from developer console on the Google Chrome and I don't see any network activity. I thought I would send API request to the Google but I really don't.

I cannot find any architectural document on this either.

Does any one has any idea?

Comment: upon looking network traffic on Telerik Fiddler I see that it does communicate with Google API. However it turns back with bad Request!

Answer (score 2):

to my knowledge, there is no official documentation for the Google Speech API that is used in Chromium, but it has been "reversed engineered" by inspecting [Chromium's source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/speech/speech_recognition_engine.cc)

when you search for it, you should find multiple blogs / tutorials that describe, how the REST API can be used

a good description on how to use it, can be found here

http://blog.travispayton.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Google-Speech-API.pdf

(with regard to the description in the PDF: the mentioned "Speech API V1" is deactivated by now, so only the "Full-Duplex API" can be used)

But note, that you need an API key via Google's [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) (for the `Speech API`); and for that you need to be registered in the [Chromium Development Group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev).
Also, using your own key, as of now, the Speech API it is limited to 50 transactions per day.